# Modelling issue

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am following a tutorial to model a cup but the mesh breaks when I try to scale a row of vertices. I have a video clip at the following link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MXR9CSRREwBQJBIL60qpt9WyhOHtNXJj/view?usp=sharing

Can you help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Answer (score 2):

You've enabled the *Proportional Editing*, which affects the vertices close to the one you manipulate, and you've chosen the *Random* falloff type, which creates erratic shapes, is it the one you want?

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. That's exactly what I needed.